# convert numbers with thousand seperator and decimal points not in " "

Tags: vba, excel

I want to convert an .xlsm macro-enabled workbook with Excel VBA to a .txt file.

The concerned Excel chart contains numbers with thousand-seperator and decimal points (e.g. 123,456,789.01).

I used this VBA code to convert in .txt:

```
Sub convert2txt()
    Dim filename As String
    filename = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("list.txt", fileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")
    If filename <> "" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Chart1").SaveAs filename, xlTextWindows
    End If
End Sub
```

But I get a .txt file where the numeric values are in double quotes `""` (i.e. `"123,456,789.01"`).

How can I save a text file so that the numbers aren't treated as strings?

Comment: Format the cells in Excel as plain numbers, which will remove the thousands separators, and then export it.

Comment: Thanks that works!! Another question: Is there a VBA command which changes "a" with "b" and "b" with "a"?

Comment: I don't know what that means. I also don't know who you're thanking or what worked.

Comment: Thank you both! All my problems are solved!